# Splunk regex: How to grep a number?

Tags: regex, numbers, splunk

If I get this line in Splunk,

```
abcd HTTP/1.1 200 0 231 edfg
```

How can I get `231` this number?

I have lots of lines like this. How can I get the number from each line and draw a graph based on these numbers?
Thanks.

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far? What were the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
| rex field=_raw "HTTP/1.1 \d+ \d+ (?<some_field_name>\d+)" | timechart avg(some_field_name) as Average
```

Comment: It works! But I want to get a "realtime" trend, for example, every minutes the real value. how should I do that?

Comment: I know, if I use timechart span=1m avg(some_field_name) as Average. I can get the average of every minute and I can use the average to present the real value in every minute, though it is not accurate.